# Fixed sidebar and navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having a problem with my CSS or Bootstrap.

I am working with the fix sidebar and navbar.

but this is the result.

I am attaching this image because I know it will help, because I cannot describe it

[image: Nabvar and Sidebar misaligned.]

In my css.

this is the sidebar

```
#wrapper {
    overflow-x:  hidden;
 }

#sidebar-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  height:100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  transition: margin .25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar-wrapper {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;

  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
```

And the navbar

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

And I used it as

```
 <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="bg-dark border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper" >
        <center>
            <img class="profile_image" src="/Images/0.png" alt="ytp-icon">
            <div class="sidebar-heading" style="color: white">HRIS</div>
        </center>

        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard", "Dashboard")" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark" style="color: white; text-align:center"><i class="fas fa-th"></i> Dashboard</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark" style="color: white; text-align:center"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i> Profile</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark" style="color: white; text-align:center">Overview</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark" style="color: white; text-align:center">Events</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark" style="color: white; text-align:center">Profile</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark" style="color: white; text-align:center">Status</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
```

AND the navbar

```
  <div id="page-content-wrapper" >
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark border-bottom">
            ......
            </nav>
  </div>
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE>
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kbaq6cnt/#&togetherjs=K5iPHIBA5s)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Make a snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS Hi. I attached the JSFIDDLE. Hope you can help me.